# How to get debug printouts from PHP?

Tags: php

I don't have access to the apache server or whatever is running on the server. I just have a free account with a web host. I do apparently have access to the .htaccess file, but I'm not sure if I feel safe enough to temper with the "nuts and bolts" as it were. So instead I tried to enable debug printouts in my php script like so:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

I'm not seeing any errors, but I know that there is an error since the entire script isn't executing.

Is there an easy way to get error printouts to show in the code that php returns? If I tried to temper with .htaccess, what would I have to do there? It's only 36 bytes long.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DO:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',"On");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php).

```
var_dump(debug_backtrace());
```